# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 freezes when Running “grub-install dummy”

Tags: installation

When installing Ubuntu 12.04 server from a disc, my system freezes up after the installation comes to Installing GRUB boot loader. I'm installing from scratch, no partitions or OS is on this computer. This is where it hangs:

> Running "grub-install dummy"

Here's my syslog file:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1122029/

And here's the specs for the computer:

General Spec

- Model: TS-0002QC-AMDX203
- Processor: AMD Dual Core E-450 1.65GHz
- Memory: 2GB
- Hard Drive: 500GB

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

No idea what's causing the freeze (your syslog doesn't contain anything I can identify as useful for diagnosis), but a possible workaround would be to use the text-mode installer from the alternate CD ([go here](http://ubuntu.com/start-download) and choose one of the options with "alternate" in the filename).

It's less pretty, but more flexible and you're more likely to be able to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a real solution for getting the installer to work - I hit this problem and the only way I found to get around it was to install ubuntu to the drive from another computer. In my case I installed via VMWare on a mac, mounting the SATA drive via a USB adaptor. After reinstalling the drive in the computer, it booted up just fine.